# Debugging network requests outcomming from server components in NextJS14 App Dir

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next.js14

Does anyone know of a tool or have any tips on how to debug requests made from server components to backend (via fetch api), specifically in a next14 app directory? Ideally, these would be visible in the browser's Network tab, but if that's not possible, I'm looking for a visual tool to facilitate monitoring outgoing requests. Constantly using console.logs is becoming tedious and irritating. Thanks

At the moment, I'm just using console.log in this way:

```
const request = await fetch(...);
console.log(request);
```

but it's not an efficient way :/

Comment: I don't know of any tools to do this from localhost but, if you deploy on Vercel, you would get this from the log there.

Comment: @grekier ye I know Vercel has something like this but unfortunately I need such a tool for localhost :(